# How can I return a string from a system call in XV6?

Tags: c, pointers, system-calls, xv6

I was wondering if I could return a string from a XV6 system call since all the system call functions have the prototype `int sys_xxx(void)` in `sysproc.h`. I know different types of parameters can be passed using `argint`, `argptr`. Is there any such mechanism for returning a pointer as well? Or are there any indirect way of returning a string other than passing the char array as a parameter?

Comment: I do not specifically know xv6, but usually, you have to provide the space for a string in userspace and pass a pointer to that space to the kernel as a syscall argument.

Comment: The only system call that *retruns* a pointer (that I can think of)  is mmap()